# how to cast void* to int[][3]

Tags: c, casting

I need to pass a variable of type `int[][3]` to a callback function which only accepts `void*` as parameter. How can I do that?

The below code does not compile:

```
void myfunc(void *param) {
    int i[][3];
    i=*param;
    printf("%d\n",i[1][2]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i[][3]={
        {1, 2, 3},
        {4, 5, 6},
        {7, 8, 9}};
    myfunc(i);
}
```

Comment: You can't cast a value to an array type. In yoyr callback, you need to define ì`as ìnt *[]` or even ìnt **`

Comment: Yes, exactly that is my problem. So what should the code look like in order to somehow pass the array through the void* pointer?

Comment: The array is only an array in your main. It decays to a pointer when passed to a function. It is OK to cast a pointer (or array) value to `void*`, so the only problem with your code is the assignment to `i` in myfunc.

Comment: Under ```void myfunc(void *param)``` the decleration ```int i[][3];``` seems to have error

Comment: Arrays can not be assigned in C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
int (*i)[3] = param;
```

Then use it as before. That’s a pointer to an array of integers.

Answer (score 3):

Detailed answer:

- The type of `i` in `main()` is `int[3][3]`, an array of arrays.
- When you use that as part of an expression, it "decays" into a pointer to the first element.
- The first element of the array `int[3][3]` is of type `int[3]`.
- A pointer to that first element is an array pointer of type `int(*)[3]`, so that is what `i` ends up as when you type `myfunc(i)`.
- Therefore, `int(*)[3]` is the correct type to use inside the function.
- If you have `int (*i)[3];` inside the function, then acessing `i[x]` will give you array number `x` in the array of arrays.
- `i[x][y]` will give you array number `x`, item number `y`. So the syntax ends up the very same as when accessing a 2D array directly.

---

Similarly, you could have written the function as `void myfunc(int param[3][3])`. Param would implicitly decay into a pointer `int(*)[3]` "between the lines", allowing you to use `param[x][y]` inside the function. It only looks like the array is passed by value, but it isn't - doing that isn't possible in C.